# Report viewer losing parameters when clicking 'back'

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services

Scenario:

Reporting services installed in Sharepoint integrated mode.

I have 2 reports:

Report **A**, simple list taking a parameter for a filter. Has a rowlevel link (Action: Go to report) to another report **B** passing in a parameter for filter.

When opening report **A** via Sharepoint (iow RSViewerPage.aspx), it prompts for the parameter. I provide it, and click 'Apply'. The report loads correctly. In the 'Parameters' pane, it shows the name and value for the parameter of report **A**.

Now I click on a link to go to report **B** with the supplied parameter. It opens the report correctly, and shows the correct name and value for the parameter for report **B**.

All OK up to here.

Now I click the 'Back' button of the report viewer (not the browser), and it takes me back correctly to report **A** with the original filter appled (as expected). The **problem** is that the 'Parameters' pane still shows the previous report's (**B**) parameter's name and value. This causes you to have to reload the entire report (**A**) from scratch.

Also, when clicking 'Apply' on the wrong parameter list, it updates to show the correct parameter names, but still uses the previous values, effective breaking the report filtering again. Again you have to reload the report (**A**) and start over.

I have tried searching Google for an answer, but nothing pops up.

This has been tested on several different servers/workstations with different levels of patches/updates to Sharepoint and SQL all with the same effect. Also the same effect in different browsers.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

PS: One would think this is a common scenario, yet it fails me why this has not been addressed or why no-one else has noticed the issue. All info on the web regarding sub- and drillthrough-reports, simply disregards the 'Back' button.

Comment: I face a similair issue (just another scenario) using Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms v11.0.0.0 .., & I don't know yet how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

My RS addin for Sharepoint was still the RTM version.

After much searching, I found the [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP1 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26728).

You can download the updated version for SQL2008 R2 SP1 from there.

The file is called `rsSharepoint.msi`.