# Go back to parent Report - Sharepoint 2010 -> Showing last report parameters

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

I'm having an issue with the parameters whenever I use the Go back to Parent Report button.

I have multiple reports each one of then has different parameters with different names. When I use the drill through ability in a report and then I do some filters in the report and then I go back, the parameters shown in the report does not belong to the current report but to the last one, I want to point out that the parameters names are differents in the reports.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "the drill through ability"?  How exactly do you "go back"?

Comment: I have 2 differents reports, one has 2 parameters and the other has 5, I drill through the one with 2 parameters to the one with 5 (with the go to report action) and then when I click "Go Back to parent report" the parameters shows must be 2, but instead appears the 5 of the other report.

Comment: I found a possible answer, I'm testing.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784311/report-viewer-losing-parameters-when-clicking-back

Comment: I would upgrade SSRS at the least, to SQL 2012 or 2014.  Rendering performance of SSRS 2008 R2 with SharePoint 2010 or 2013 was awful, e.g. http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2011/1/25/whats-up-with-the-slow-ssrs-r2-rendering-in-sharepoint-2010.html